# is_front_page() not working wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, scripting, blogs

I'm trying to load a script from "functions.php" just when i'm in the front page.
I set a static page called "home" in the reading options.
The home page loads the "front-page.php" template correctly but the conditional script loading doesn't work.

This is what I have in my "functions.php" file:

```
wp_register_script('nivoslider', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/libs/nivoslider.js', false, false, true);

if (is_front_page()) {   
   wp_enqueue_script('nivoslider'); 
}
```

Why isn't this loading as expected? What's happening here?

Comment: Try posting your query on wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ok, posted it here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/27953/is-front-page-not-working-wordpress

Answer (score 1):

```
$isfrontpage = false;   
if( is_front_page() || is_home() ) {    

    $isfrontpage = true;    

} else {

    $current = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $site = get_site_url();
    $site = str_replace('http://', '', $site);
    $site = str_replace('https://', '', $site);
    $site = str_replace('www', '', $site);

    if( $site == $current || $site . '/' == $current ){
        $isfrontpage = true
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page) -

> It returns TRUE when the main blog page is being displayed and the
>   Settings->Reading->Front page displays is set to "Your latest posts",
>   or when is set to "A static page" and the "Front Page" value is the
>   current Page being displayed.

Just setting it to use your front page template does not make it a front page. It is the front page when either of the conditions above are true. Therefore both must be false for this page you created.

Also, is this just included inline with functions.php or are you actually hooking into the head?

Comment: It is hooked. All my other scripts work perfectly. I read the Codex multiple times but I can't seem to find the right answer. I also tried with `is_page('Home')` with no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry I don't know the answer. You will definitely do better at wordpress.stackexchange.com though. I upvoted your question there so hopefully it gets some more attention.

Comment: I just found this after some googling - could this be happening to you? is_home() or is_front_page() did not work in the footer. I figured out it turns FALSE after the query_posts() or get_post(). Use wp_reset_query to fix it.

Comment: I tried `wp_reset_query()`, still no luck. This is soooo strange.

Comment: Weird thing is if i use `!is_front_page()` the script loads just fine. What the heck! `var_dump(is_front_page())` returns FALSE

Answer (score 0):

`is_front_page();` will not work in functions.php as expected since the functions.php initializes before its able to detect your "front_page.php"

Answer (score 0):

Here's the right way to enqueue scripts:

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_enqueue_scripts', 5 );

function my_custom_enqueue_scripts(){
    wp_register_script('nivoslider', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/libs/nivoslider.js', false, false, true);

    if (is_front_page()) {   
       wp_enqueue_script('nivoslider'); 
    }
}

?>
```